# VBA form - Possible change textbox value if exists only once in range

Tags: vba, excel

I am ussing "Save" and "Change" button for add/change order numbers in range A:A. It is working if I enter new order number ("Save" button) but not working if I want change old order number ("Change" button) that already exist in range A:A

```
    Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() 'Change Button
Dim sonsat As Long

    If ListBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then
    MsgBox "Select ", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
    End If
    Sheets("orders").Range("A:A").Find(ListBox1.Text).Activate
    sonsat = ActiveCell.Row

        If Not Columns(1).Find(Me.TextBox1.Value, , , xlWhole, , , False) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox Me.TextBox1.Value & " Already used ", , "Same number"
            Cancel = True
            Exit Sub
        End If


    Cells(sonsat, 1) = TextBox1
    Cells(sonsat, 2) = TextBox2
    Cells(sonsat, 3) = CDbl(TextBox3)
    Cells(sonsat, 4) = Format(TextBox4, "d.m.yyyy")
    Cells(sonsat, 5) = Format(TextBox5, "d.m.yyyy")
    Cells(sonsat, 6) = CDbl(TextBox6)


    Call Main 'Progress Bar
    MsgBox "Changed"
    ListBox1.List = Sheets("orders").Range("a2:l" & [a65536].End(3).Row).Value 'For refresh listbox
    End Sub
```

I need update this code that can allow me change order number if exists only once in range A:A. Those orders numbers are entered by user via textbox (VBA form)

Comment: what sub/function is that code placed in? what is `Cancel`?

Comment: Simply I need check all numbers that are in range only once before change code is done.

Comment: add examples of your data: a "before" and "after" scenarios" would do